# Why we say map-reduce solves "Paper reference" problems better than traditional methods?

Tags: algorithm, hadoop, dictionary, statistics, reduce

It's said when we wish to do statistics among paper references, map-reduce could do much better than traditional ways, as traditional ways involves a lot of memory/disk switches. I don't quite find out why traditional ways is not good.

Suppose I run map-reduce on just one machine(no cluster), does it still solve some problems better than traditional ways?

Or in another word, does the algorithm paradigm of "map-reduce" itself, has some advantages in solving problems, from algorithm point of view?

Thanks.

Comment: `It's said` who and where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At *best* M/R allows re-applying the same algorithms as the advanced stats packages. But more typically some sacrifices are made in the algorithms used  - to allow for running in a distributed fashion.  Map/Reduce provides no "magic" in terms of - say - providing a more uniformly randomized distribution during cross-fold sampling (or any other sampling methodology).

For a small dataset that fits in memory M/R is usually worse than your traditional packages - due to compromises made in the algorithm for scalability.  You start to see an advantage to M/R when using large datasets that are prohibitive  to fully sample on a single machine.  Using R / Matlab / SAS would typically require down-sampling - and possibly by orders or magnitude.